# ios objective c Skip video preview option from UiImagepickercontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

```
 UIImagePickerController *camera = [UIImagePickerController new];
 camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 camera.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
 [camera setVideoQuality:UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium];
 camera.videoMaximumDuration = 180;
 camera.delegate = self;
```

We are adding camera controller to record video but it shows preview of video after end i just want to remove this preview option.

Comment: try `camera.showsCameraControls = NO;`

Comment: Its not working...Hides capture button.